# Needing money to travel from Ghana

Tags: international-travel, scams, ghana

I have a friend communicating with an American living in Ghana. She says she needs $6000 to pay off debts before she could move to Spain. Is this true?

Comment: It’s almost certainly a scam, especially if they’ve never met. She probably isn’t American (or even female).

Comment: A genuine American in this situation would be well advised to contact the embassy. They can provide *loans* for the flight home and legal assistance. Since they contacted your friend, they're scammers.